# Android Edittext: Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullreferenceexception

When I run the code below, the username in the edittext is never found. I have tested with and without a username, but when the button is clicked it sends a null object to the eventlistener. I am new to android and confused why it is not returning a string when the username edittext contains a username.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = LoginFragment.class.getSimpleName();
public  EditText username = null;
public View root = null;

public interface eventListener {
    void someEvent(String s);
}

eventListener eventListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_splashpage, null, false);
    username = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.login_username);
    Button login_button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String usernameString = username.getText().toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "Button Clicked" + usernameString);
            if (!usernameString.isEmpty()) {
                eventListener.someEvent(usernameString);
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(root, "No username provided. Try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

}

Anyway, thank you for your help and time

Comment: Calling getText() should already return a string, there is no need to also call toString().

Comment: getText returns an android.text.Editable, not a string

Comment: How can the event listener ever get a null object?  This code would crash with NullPointerException before that happens.

Comment: why you are instantiating edit text to null??

Comment: Yes. It crashes with an "Attempt to invoke interface method on null object reference"

Comment: @VivekMishra it fixed someone else's similar problem. I thought it would help

Comment: Yeah, I checked the id's, and they are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `eventListener` is null that's why you get the NullPointerException.

Since raw interfaces only provide the contract on what the derived class should do, you must also create the logic behind it:

```
private interface eventListener {
  void onEvent(String string);
}

eventListener listener = new eventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onEvent(String string) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onEvent " + string);
  }
};
```

I'm not sure if you even want an interface here as a simple method would do:

```
public void onLogin(String username) {
  Log.e(TAG, "onLogin " + username)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at this line

```
eventListener.someEvent(usernameString);
```

Where Interface eventListener was not initialised,  Can you do something like this ?

```
eventListener ev = new eventListener(){
void someEvent(usernameString);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is it as eventlistner is "abstract; cannot be instantiated"

Comment: I have edited that and can you do something like that ? Try once